# Why does combining if elif else, str.contains, and .any() in a pandas dataframe give me uniform result?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, if-statement, dataframe

I try to make new lable tor every lines in a dataset based on text that contained in previous column, heres my code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\data july 2017.xlsx')
#data['Description'].fillna('')
pawoon = data[data['Description'].str.contains('Pawoon')]
pawoon['time'] = "0"
if pawoon.Description.str.contains('1 Bulan').any():
    pawoon['time'] = 1
elif pawoon.Description.str.contains('3 Bulan').any():
    pawoon['time'] = 3
elif pawoon.Description.str.contains('6 bulan').any():
    pawoon['time'] = 6
elif pawoon.Description.str.contains('1 Tahun').any():
    pawoon['time'] = 1
else:
    pawoon['time'] = 0
```

Here's the partial result that i've got, when I print partial result of the code above

```
Pawoon POS Software (1 Bulan)   1
Software Pawoon (6 bulan)       1
Pawoon POS Software (1 Tahun)   1
Pawoon POS Software (3 Bulan)   1
Pawoon POS Software (1 Bulan)   1
```

The result that I expected is showed below (based on if elif else statement that I mention in my code)

```
Pawoon POS Software (1 Bulan)   1
Software Pawoon (6 bulan)       6
Pawoon POS Software (1 Tahun)   12
Pawoon POS Software (3 Bulan)   3
Pawoon POS Software (1 Bulan)   1
```

Why does it's happen? How to get my desired result?
I guess `.any()` should be change, but if I change to `.all` every result uniformly `0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need multiple if else statements you can use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
m1 = pawoon.Description.str.contains('1 Bulan')
m2 = pawoon.Description.str.contains('3 Bulan')
m3 = pawoon.Description.str.contains('6 Bulan')
m4 = pawoon.Description.str.contains('1 Tahun')

pawoon['time'] = np.select([m1,m2,m3,m4], [1,3,6,12], default=0)
print (pawoon)
                     Description  time
0  Pawoon POS Software (1 Bulan)     1
1      Software Pawoon (6 Bulan)     6
2  Pawoon POS Software (1 Tahun)    12
3  Pawoon POS Software (3 Bulan)     3
4  Pawoon POS Software (1 Bulan)     1
```

Comment: I didn't know about `numpy.select`

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

---

```
 #Practice data frame
df = pd.DataFrame({'description':list('abc')})

 #Initialize the column
df['time'] = -1

 #Just one example of how to do this
df.loc[df.description.str.contains('a'),'time'] = 10
```

Result is

```
description time
a           10
b           -1
c           -1
```

Your problem is that you were changing the entire column by doing `df['time'] = 1`.  `loc` is a much better way of achieving this.